# How do you use max_by with an enumerable if you need to filter out values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I do this?  Right now it's creating nil values when user is male, and then the <==> operation is failing.

```
@user.max_by{|user_id, user| user.height if user.female?}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chain these together, so do your selection before your aggregation

```
@user.select{|user| user.female?}.max_by{|user_id, user| user.height}
```

Also, you should be able to simplify (just a little syntax sugar):

```
@user.select(&:female?).max_by(&:height)
```

Comment: cool, what is the process you use in the second example called?  I want to find out more about that.  Thanks!

Comment: The second example is using [Symbol#to_proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Symbol.src/M000780.html). Note that it will be [quite a bit slower](http://blog.gregspurrier.com/articles/relative-performance-of-symbol-to-proc-in-popular-ruby-implementations) than standard blocks in some versions of Ruby.

Comment: @Greg Campbell -- excellent post ... anybody who reads this should read that link. headline for me: both ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 are fine to use the above syntax. If you're using another, check the link.